# Bokeh callbacks scope

Tags: javascript, python

As far as I know, in Python, variables declared outside of a function can be accessed by the latter, but cannot be modified (except if we declare them as global in the function, see https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/scope-of-variables-python).

I'm learning to use Bokeh, and I want to modify instances (dropdowns, tables...) through callbacks. Based on the previous paragraph, callbacks cannot modify these instances if the latter are not declared as global. But the code sample below works ...

```
userList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
folderList = ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
s = MultiSelect(options=userList, size=4, width=1000)
ti = TextInput(placeholder='Enter reference')

def populateDropdown(attr, old, new):
  #nonlocal s, ti
  if new == 0:
    options = userList

  else:
    options =folderList
  s.options = options
  ti.callback = CustomJS(args=dict(options=s.options, s=s),code="s.options = 
options.filter(i =>i[0].toLowerCase().includes(cb_obj.value.toLowerCase()));console.log(options);")

usersFoldersChoice = RadioButtonGroup(labels=["Users", "Folders"])
usersFoldersChoice.on_change('active', populateDropdown)
```

A multiselect is prepopulated with `userlist`. There are two radio buttons, if one clicks on "Folders", the callback "populateDropdown" is triggered. This callback has to repopulate the multiselect `s` with `folderList` and also update the callback linked to the text input `ti`. Here, `s` and `ti` are modified without declaring them as global, and it works, which is confusing me.

In addition, if I don't understand why I have to update the callback linked to `ti` in order to take the change of `s` into account (at first, the callback was directly assigned to `ti` during its declaration, but it did not work...)

Thanks in advance for any clarification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your intuition is not quite right. You cannot *assign* to variables outside a function. That is, this function will not update the value of `x` outside the function:

```
x = {}

def f():
    x = [] # this makes a new local variable
```

However, if the objects outside the function are *mutable*, i.e. they can be modified "in place", then there is no problem to update them by calling methods on them. For example:"

```
x = {}

def f():
    x['a'] = 10  # this will update the x dict in place
```

That is why Bokeh callbacks can manipulate the widget or data source objects defined outside the functions.

I don't quite understand your last question.

Comment: Oh I see! So Bokeh callbacks don't need to declare variables they want to modify as "global" since these objects can be modified inplace, correct?

Comment: My last question means: I put a `console.log(options)` in the JS callback code. If I put this code outside of `populateDropdown`, the log always returns `userList` . I had to put it IN `populateDropdown` to make it log folderList. It's like the JS callback had to be "updated" along with the dropdown...

Comment: Yes that's correct. For the other: Maybe a bug? Hard to say more without a complete, minimal script to run.

Comment: Hum okay I'll try to figure this out. Thanks anyway for your answer!